# Mapping between Childs' List in Same Class

Tags: c#, oop

The question looks easy but I am really can't get the trick same time I don't want to go through a work around.I have this XML file

```
<Master>
  <Parent1>
     <child1/>
     <child1/>
     <child1/>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent2>
     <child2/>
     <child2/>
     <child2/>
  </Parent2>
</Master>
```

I deserialize it in the current class structure

```
Class Master
{
  List<child1> Parent1;
  List<child2> Parent2;
}
```

Child2 is displayed on the UI whenever it changed shall change child1 had same ID as child2.The problem is that in child2 I have no access to Parent1 so how can go backward to change in child1.I need a good solution not a workaround.

**Edit:** Child1 and Child2 two different classes but there is certain mapping between their properties.

Comment: yes sure Child1 and Child2 are classes

Comment: Are `child1` and `child2` different classes or different instances of the same class? Same question for Parent1-2..

Comment: Different classes but contains some common properties

Comment: It's not clear what are your constraints, and why can't you use events, and event handlers for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to let each parent know about which children was added/removed.
Each parent will get the event and will handle it if it's a matching child (or relevant due to other logic).

Two public objects which are used for communication between parent and master:

```
public enum ChangeType { Added, Removed }

public delegate void ChildChangeEvent(Parent parent, Child child, ChangeType changeType);
```

**The parent class has two main roles**- raising an event if it has a child that was added/removed, and handling this event if raised by other parents and it's relevant for them.

```
class Parent
{
    public event ChildChangeEvent ChildChangeEvent;

    private List<Child> _children;

    public void Add(Child child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);

        ChildChangeEvent(this, child, ChangeType.Added);
    }

    public void Remove(Child child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);

        ChildChangeEvent(this, child, ChangeType.Removed);
    }

    public void NotifyChange(Parent parent, Child child, ChangeType changeType)
    {
        //do where you want with this info.. change local id or whatever logic you need
    }
}
```

The `Master` class should notify all parents about the child added/removed
event that was raised by one of the parents:

```
class Master
{
    private List<Parent> _parents;

    public void AddParent(Parent parent)
    {
        _parents.Add(parent);
        parent.ChildChangeEvent += parent_ChildChangeEvent;
    }

    void parent_ChildChangeEvent(Parent parent, Child child, ChangeType changeType)
    {
        foreach (var notifyParent in _parents)
        {
            notifyParent.NotifyChange(parent, child, changeType);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yosi for your answer,the problem is if I haven't used the function of add and remove to fill parent I will not be able to raise any event second thing Parent1 and Parent2 are two different classes

Comment: So use this function to add/remove. If Parent1-2 are different classes make them inherit from an abstract class with this logic. If you want a permenant good solution, you will need to make changes.

Comment: I fill these data through serializing this XML file so can have certain solution to keep serializing working same time make this  mapping

Comment: There isn't any reason that this implementation will break backward compatibility, or will not be able to support this with some modifications. Seems like there is information you are not exposing